# Use php data from controller (or view) in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, view, controller

I have a question about using data pulled from the database in javascript.

In my controller I have this:

```
$this->view->projects = $projectsarray;
```

I send the array to my view. There I will loop through my array and show the titles. Now I need to get that array in javascript because I want to create a highchart with the data...

Does anyone knows how I could do this easily?

EDIT:
I now have this in my controller: (overviewcontroller)

```
public function getprojectdataAction($id){

}
```

In my javascript file:

```
var id = 1;
$.post('/overview/getprojectdata/',{id:id},function(data){
    alert("test");
});
```

But I get the error that the resource can't be found:

> POST http://www.namesite.com/overview/getprojectdata/ 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `$this->view->projects` is array or object

in your view file

```
<script>

var projects = <?php echo json_encode($this->projects);?>;
console.log(projects);
</script>
```

then watch your firebug ...

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by converting array to JSON you can send a ajax request to same controller

and return echo json_encode($array);  then you can use directly with responce by decoding it...

```
$.post('controller/action',{id:id},function(data){
    var arrayJson=JSON.parse(data);
});
```

you can use arrayJson as data array...

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode in the php part of the code to generate a javascript object out of your array. For example:

```
$php = array("myAttrib" => "hallo");
echo json_encode($php);
```

and in javascript you can use

```
alert (output.myAttrib);
```

, where output refers to echo json_encode(php). This code would open a box showing "hallo". Your question seems to be quite similar to [how to use json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377570/how-to-use-json-encode). For creating of a highchart also this post [Highcharts data series issue with ajax/json and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058136/highcharts-data-series-issue-with-ajax-json-and-php?rq=1) could be of interest for you.