# Highcharts live data, json ajax

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, highcharts

My head is going to blow.

livedata.php loads json when page open.
live.php add point to graph.

From livedata.php i got output like this:

```
[["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37],["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37],["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37],["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37],["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37],["Date.UTC(2016, 07-1, 28, 15, 08)",37]]
```

live.php output - only last row, looks like

```
["Date.UTC('.2016, 07-1, 29, 15, 40.')", 44]
```

I've got chart, live addPoint working, but no date on x-axis. What i do wrong?

JS

```
var chart;

function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 120; // shift if the series is 

                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point));

                setTimeout(requestData, 10000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'livedata.php',
        success: function(point) {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'areaspline',

                    events: {
                load: requestData
            }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',

                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',

                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'


                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },


                series: [{

            name: 'Random data',
            data:  eval(point )
        }]
            });
        },    

    });


});
```

live.php

```
global $dbConnection;
    $stmt = $dbConnection->query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as dataa, humidity FROM sensorsdata order by id desc limit 1');    
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $date_raw = strftime('%Y, %m-1, %d, %H, %M', strtotime($row[dataa]));
        $date_complete = "Date.UTC('.$date_raw.')";
    $ar = array($date_complete, $row[humidity]);
    echo json_encode($ar, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

livedata.php

```
global $dbConnection;
$stmt = $dbConnection->query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as dataa, humidity FROM sensorsdata');    

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $date_raw = strftime('%Y, %m-1, %d, %H, %M', strtotime($row[dataa]));
    $date_complete = 'Date.UTC('.$date_raw.')';
    $hum_for_chart[] = [$date_complete, $row[humidity]];

}

echo json_encode($hum_for_chart, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Chart:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhicK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its problem of your data try to make string like,

live.php

```
....
$date_complete = "Date.UTC('.$date_raw.')";
$ar = "[".$date_complete.",". $row[humidity]."]";
echo json_encode($ar);
```

livedata.php

```
....
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $date_raw = strftime('%Y, %m-1, %d, %H, %M', strtotime($row[dataa]));
    $date_complete = 'Date.UTC('.$date_raw.')';
    $hum_for_chart[] = "[".$date_complete.",". $row[humidity]."]";
}
....
```

You can refer [highcharts-data-series-issue-with-ajax-json-and-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058136/highcharts-data-series-issue-with-ajax-json-and-php)

Comment: with string type i got an error
Highcharts error #12: www.highcharts.com/errors/12
highcharts.js:286 Uncaught TypeError: h.splice is not a function

Answer (score 0):

i've got it! 2 days of mind blowing ))))

Thanks to [Rohan Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817690/rohan-kumar) for link. 
I made changes from date.utc to unix timestamp.

```
$datetimeUTC = ((strtotime($row[dataa])+ 10800) * 1000);
$data[] = [$datetimeUTC, $row[humidity]];
echo json_encode($data);
```

- 10800 - that is +3 hours (Moscow timezone)

The output is

```
[[1469718529000,37],[1469718529000,37],[1469718530000,37],[1469718531000,37]]
```

And that's it, date axis started working!